# Stacked bar plot using factor lists in base R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am hoping to make a stacked bar plot to show two factors. The questions and answers I can find on this site that address this problem all work with data that appears to be in a matrix format and use ggplot2. My data is in lists of observations, like this:

```
mydata = data.frame(V1=c("A","B","B","C","C"), V2=c("X","X","Y","Z","Z"))
```

I would like to show categories of V1 on the x axis of my plot, but stacked to show the proportions of V2 in each bar.

I can use the "count" function in the plyr library to find the frequency of each observation,

```
library(plyr)
mydata.count = count(mydata)
```

but I don't know how to structure my barplot command to group data by the level of V1: `barplot(mydata.count$freq)` separates all combinations of V1 and V2 into separate bars.

If possible, I would like to create this plot using the base R barplot functions so that it is visually consistent with other plots in my study.

Comment: `barplot(t(table(mydata)))`

Comment: @d.b, thank you, that is exactly what I needed. Do you know how to determine how colors are assigned to factor levels?

Comment: ```barplot(t(table(mydata)),
        col = c("cyan","darkred","navy"),
        legend.text = c("X","Y","Z"))``` colors are already assigned but `barplot` uses a gamma-corrected grey palette for colors as out input (i.e. `t(table(mydata))`) is a matrix.

Comment: @d.b please add as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `table` to create a contingency table of the counts for all combinations of `V1` and `V2`. Then, use `barplot` to create the stacked bar plot. When used with matrix, `barplot` creates stacked vertical bars where the columns appear on x-axis - so it may be necessary to transpose the data.

```
m = t(table(mydata))

colors = c("red", "green", "blue")
graphics.off()
windows(8, 6)
barplot(m, col = colors)
legend("topleft", legend = row.names(m), fill = colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility with `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(mydata)), aes(x=V1, y=Freq, fill=V2)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(mydata)), aes(x=V2, y=Freq, fill=V1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]